# How to place Textboxes Side by Side in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, position

I want to know how to make it so that the two square textboxes are placed next to each other side by side rather than on top of each other.

CSS

```
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.textbox { 
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    width: 300px; 
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
} 

.textbox1 { 
    border: 1px dotted #000000; 
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    width: 150px; 
} 

.textbox2 { 
    border: 1px dotted #000000; 
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    width: 150px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="textbox"type="text"> 
<input class="textbox1"type="text"> 
<input class="textbox2"type="text">
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `display:inline-block;` for your inputs

Also, I don't think you understand how classes work. `textbox` is completely different than `textbox1`, they won't share any properties. If you are looking to set each of their CSS properties individually then you should use IDs (using `#textbox1` in your CSS as opposed to `.textbox1`). What I would recommend is putting all of your common styles (such as border, outline, height, and perhaps also your radiuses) in a class applied to each `input` and use IDs to style the ones individually. The other option is to use the attribute contains selector like `[class *= textbox]` which will select all elements with "textbox" in the class name.

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zm4SN/), assuming you want the border radius on each of the inputs. If you don't, simply move it from the `textbox` class and put it in the `#first` section